# Attach multiple javaagents in catalinaopts

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, javaagents, jolokia

I have a java application running in tomcat8 and have jolokia.jar as one of the java agent options to Catalina_opts. Now I want one more metrics collector to be added to this catalina_opts. How can I add it?

Current Catalina_opts
`CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS_APPEND -javaagent:$JWS_HOME/lib/jolokia.jar=port=xxxx,protocol=https,clientPrincipal=cn=system:masterproxy,useSslClientAuthentication=true,extraClientCheck=true,host=0.0.0.0,discoveryEnabled=false"`

What I want
`CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS_APPEND -javaagent:$JWS_HOME/lib/jolokia.jar=port=xxxx,protocol=https,clientPrincipal=cn=system:masterproxy,useSslClientAuthentication=true,extraClientCheck=true,host=0.0.0.0,discoveryEnabled=false -javaagent:./jmx-0.9.jar=1234:config.yaml"`

I am not sure if we can use multiple java agents. If so can anyone point me on how to include the multiple java agents

Answer (score 3):

You can. Simply add multiple arguments each specifying an agents. Agents are activated in the order they are specified on the command line:

```
java -javaagent:foo.jar=arg1 -javaagent:bar.jar=arg2 ...
```

`JAVA_OPTS` or `CATALINE_OPTS`are only alternative ways of specifing something on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a combined Jolokia and Prometheus' jmx_exporter you might want to have a look at [agent-bond](https://github.com/fabric8io/agent-bond), a *super agent* which combines multiple agents into one. Currently, only Jolokia and jmx_exporter are supported, but other agents could be easily added.

The advantage of such a combined approach is that you only have to deal with a single agent jar and a bit simpler command line configuration.